# for loop is not running after ssh connection

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a script which will do ssh to few hosts (via for loop) and run few commands on remote host with help of for another for loop. 
I have written something like below but second for loop is not returning anything after doing ssh.

PS: ssh set-up has been done so no issues while doing ssh. Issue is with second for loop.

```
for ((i=11; i <= 16; i++))
do
echo $i
ssh abc$i.uk.com << EOF
cd /home
  for j in `ls -1`
   do
     ls -lrt $j/*
   done
EOF
done
```

Comment: The command substitution (the backticks) happens on the client side, is that what you want?

Comment: Also, on the topic of `for` and `ls`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: yeah, I should be done at remote server side after ssh.

Comment: You could use `<<'EOF'`. Or use `for j in *`. Or no loop and just `ls -lrt */*`, or even replace the whole heredoc with `ls -lrt /home/*/*`.

Comment: In second loop, I have just given the example of ls -lrt, I would like to remove directories whichever present in the directories of /home. for eg: /home/a/temp so I would like to delete only temp not a and it should be done one by one under /home.

Comment: `rm -r /home/*/*` should suffice.

Comment: what is initial value of $j ? and where you increment it ?

Comment: ls -1 in command substitution will get the value and assign to j and it will automatically increment till all file and directories covered in /home directory.